# Performance trade-offs of breaking up a document or keeping it whole

Tags: mongodb, nosql

My question is about performance optimization with respect to data structure in MongoDB/NoSql

I have a collection with very large documents.  I will need to iterate through the entire collection for data analytics several times per minute.

Assumptions: 
- The number of documents will be < 10,000
- only a small portion of the document is used for the number crunching
- the documents will not change often

My question is:  would I get significantly boost performance by creating a cache collection with only the fields needed for number crunching?  Doing so would require the overhead of maintaining the cache table.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's depends on whether the documents are in the memory (Or your ram is large enough to cache them).

If no, cache will boost the performance in a significant way.